# Router gives no exported member error after migration to Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, tslint

I just migrated to Angular 8 and I started getting the error

```
Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/router/router"' has no exported member 'NoPreloading'.
```

This error comes from the line:

```
import { NoPreloading, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

It happens for all members of `@angular/router`. What am I doing wrong? Dispite the error everything still works fine.

Comment: not sure why the down vote, I had exact same error after upgrading to 8.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be due to some missing node-modules in your old project after the migration. Here are the steps to follow,

1. Remove your **package-lock.json** file
2. Delete the **node_modules** folder from your project’s working directory
3. Run `npm install`

Comment: run "rm -rf node_modules" in your bash terminal, then "npm i" to reinstall packages

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deleting your node_modules folder and re-installing them by running NPM install or yarn install? Often these migrations to a higher version cause inconsistencies between packages.